# Class function returning invalid lvalue

Tags: c++, return-value

Hi I am now writing a program handling matrix manipulation and I am struggling on the error handling issue in a member function.

Given a function

```
double & MATRIX::elements(int i, int j) const;
```

it is the function that can return a reference back, so the function can be a 
lvalue, e.g.

```
object.elements(1,2)= 2; // I can change the value matrix element (1,2) to be 2
```

I assume that some people may enter the index of the matrix wrongly (i.e.invalid value of i and j) that the element (i,j) does not exist. Therefore, I write an if-else statement, however, I wonder what should I return when invalid values of i and j are found?? Can I prevent the function from returning  anything so situations like

```
object.elements(100,100000)= 2; // where the matrix size is only 3x3
```

won' t happen??

P.S. I store the matrix elements in a dynamic array when I create the object

Comment: It looks like that member function should not be `const`.

Comment: @NathanOliver how to throw the exception?? I cannot find a way to return properly...

Comment: Exceptions are perfect for this kind of scenario. Otherwise you will have to redesign your function to return an error code. You will also have to check the error code for every invocation.

Comment: There's a good tutorial [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three practical possibilities:

- `assert` the precondition, and rely on testing to root out all invalid calls, or
- throw an exception when the precondition is not true, or
- return an easily recognized-as-such error value.

In the old days one also included schemes such as calling a user-provided error function, but really what could it do except terminate or throw an exception.

The third possibility, returning a known-as-such error value, may appear unsuitable for your present predicament, which ideally would return a `double&` which would be immediately used. But in general it's a valid option. For example, it can be implemented as a Boost `optional`.

---

In passing, some general advice.

For the given code,

```
double & MATRIX::elements(int i, int j) const;
```

usually a `const` method does not provide read/write access, it defeats the purpose. However there are exceptions, such as for a proxy object. But on the third and gripping hand, the above code is not for such objects.

Also, consider reserving ALL UPPERCASE identifiers for macros. That way you can avoid some name collisions. Remember that macros don't respect scopes, and since a great many people use all uppercase identifiers for macros, while few do otherwise, the chance of a collision, resulting in undesirable text substitution, is greater with uppercase used for ordinary identifiers.